# Levi-Civita symboI in 4 dimensions $\epsilon^{ijkl}$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, analysis, tensors

I don't get it with the permutations. I believe that this is once like this:

$\epsilon^{0123} = \epsilon^{1230} = \epsilon^{2301} = \epsilon^{3012} = 1$

Then there are the others. But I have no idea whether they are zero or -1.

$\epsilon^{0132} = \epsilon^{1320} = \epsilon^{3201} = \epsilon^{2013} = \alpha_1$

$\epsilon^{0213} = \epsilon^{2130} = \epsilon^{1302} = \epsilon^{3021} = \alpha_2$

$\epsilon^{0231} = \epsilon^{2310} = \epsilon^{3102} = \epsilon^{1023} = \alpha_3$

$\epsilon^{0312} = \epsilon^{3120} = \epsilon^{1203} = \epsilon^{2031} = \alpha_4$

$\epsilon^{0321} = \epsilon^{3210} = \epsilon^{2103} = \epsilon^{1032} = \alpha_5$

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: do you know how to factorize permutations with transpositions? if the number is even or odd the the sign will be + or - respectively

Comment: I only know that the Levi-Civita symbol has the value 1, -1 or 0. With three it is quite easy. If you take 012 and turn the numbers clockwise, it's always 1. If you take 021 and turn the numbers clockwise, it's always -1. And for all other cases, it's zero.

Comment: This is all explained in the Wikipedia article isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Levi-Civita symbol is defined by the sign of the permutation... it is $+1$ for even permutations (those that require an even number of pairwise swaps) and $-1$ for odd ones.  So $\epsilon^{0123}=1$ by definition (no swaps), and then all the other values can be defined by total antisymmetry (antisymmetry under the exchange of any two indices).

For instance, then,
$$
\epsilon^{01\underline{32}}=-\epsilon^{0123}=-1,
$$
and
$$
\epsilon^{0\underline{3}2\underline{1}}=-\epsilon^{0123}=-1.
$$

Comment: So every $\alpha$ is -1 for me?

Comment: @Physics No. Why would you think that? For instance $1032$ is two swaps away from $0123$ (swapping the numbers $0,1$ and $2,3$) so $\epsilon^{1032}=+1$.

Comment: Does this mean that all my equals signs are wrong? I always thought that if I rotate the numbers clockwise that then the number would be preserved. So that seems to be valid only for an odd number of indices, correct?

Comment: Right, rotating the indices preserves the sign only for an odd number of indices.